# How to calculate most frequent occurring terms/words in a document collection/corpus using R?

Tags: r, frequency, corpus, word-frequency

First I create a document term matrix like below

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
```

Then I take the sum of the occurance of each word vectors as below

```
totalsums <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
```

My totalsums (R says type 'double') looks like below for first 7 elements.

```
aaab   aabb    aabc   aacc   abbb   abbc    abcc    ...
   9      2      10      4      7      3      12    ...
```

I managed to sort this with the following command

```
sorted.sums <- sort(totalsums, decreasing=T)
```

Now I want to extract the first 4 terms/words with the highest sums which are greater than value 5.
I could get the first 4 highest with `sorted.sums[1:4]` but how can I set a threshold value?

I managed to do this with the `order` function like below but, is there a way to do this than sort function or without using `findFreqTerms` fucntion?

```
ord.totalsums <- order(totalsums)
findFreqTerms(dtm, lowfreq=5)
```

Appreciate your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
sorted.sums[sorted.sums > 5][1:4]
```

But if you have at least 4 values that are greater than 5 only using `sorted.sums[1:4]` should work as well.

To get the words you can use `names`.

```
names(sorted.sums[sorted.sums > 5][1:4])
```

Comment: Thanks, ``sorted.sums[sorted.sums > 5]`` gives me both the word and the sum. Is there a way to extract only the word? I should have been clear about this in my question. I made an edit.

Comment: You can use `names` to get the word. Updated my answer for that.